# Correct Topology for Quadruped Legs?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, unity, topology

I am working on a **stylized low poly cat** for a Unity game and am having a difficult time finding suitable topology for the legs or knowing if I am on the right track.

How can I achieve good edge flow for the shoulders/hips to prevent any strange deformations?

Here is the stage I am at:

**Low Poly with no modifiers** 
[image: Low Poly]

**With Subsurface modifier** 
[image]

Does this look suitable for a low poly character for animation purposes?

I feel like there needs to be better edge loops starting from the shoulders but I want to avoid unnecessary topology by making more loop cuts.

Comment: It all goes to the style you're aiming to. If realistic then the leg is too short, lacks some proportions and curvature. If non-realistic note that some proportions should be preserved as well, just like e.g. how this leg is going to be bent, there doesn't seem to be any geometry for smooth bending and it's not visible from the model that this leg is being bent when cat walks. General amount of loops is fine, there aren't quite a lot of them as for now. You can also search for "cat shoulder topology" on google to see some references for that

Comment: Here you go: http://www.zbrushcentral.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=365454. You can follow this and you'll be fine.